# How to send an xml file using http post in android. Where i put the xml files in the code

Tags: android, xml, http, post

I need to send an xml file using http post in android. I am new to this. Where i put the xml in the android and how to send it using the code.

The sample of the xml looks like this

```
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?
    minorRev=[current minorRev #]
    &cid=55505
    &apiKey=[xxx-yourOwnKey-xxx]
    &customerUserAgent=[xxx]
    &customerIpAddress=[xxx]
    &locale=en_US
    &currencyCode=USD
    &xml=
    <HotelListRequest>
    <city>Seattle</city>
    <stateProvinceCode>WA</stateProvinceCode>
    <countryCode>US</countryCode>
    <arrivalDate>08/01/2012</arrivalDate>
    <departureDate>08/03/2012</departureDate>
    <RoomGroup>
    <Room>
    <numberOfAdults>2</numberOfAdults>
     </Room>
     </RoomGroup>
     <numberOfResults>1</numberOfResults>
         <supplierCacheTolerance>MED_ENHANCED</supplierCacheTolerance>
         </HotelListRequest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating xml file

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 dbfac.setNamespaceAware(true);
 DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
 try {
    docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 DOMImplementation domImpl = docBuilder.getDOMImplementation();
 Document doc = domImpl.createDocument("http://coggl.com/InsertTrack","TrackEntry", null);
 doc.setXmlVersion("1.0");
 doc.setXmlStandalone(true);

 Element trackElement = doc.getDocumentElement();

 Element CompanyId = doc.createElement("CompanyId");
 CompanyId.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("1"));
 trackElement.appendChild(CompanyId);

 Element CreatedBy = doc.createElement("CreatedBy");
 CreatedBy.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("6"));
 trackElement.appendChild(CreatedBy);

 Element DepartmentId = doc.createElement("DepartmentId");
 DepartmentId.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("4"));
 trackElement.appendChild(DepartmentId);

 Element IsBillable = doc.createElement("IsBillable");
 IsBillable.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("1"));
 trackElement.appendChild(IsBillable);

 Element ProjectId = doc.createElement("ProjectId");
 ProjectId.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("1"));
 trackElement.appendChild(ProjectId);

 Element StartTime = doc.createElement("StartTime");
 StartTime.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("2012-03-14 10:44:45"));
 trackElement.appendChild(StartTime);

 Element StopTime = doc.createElement("StopTime");
 StopTime.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("2012-03-14 11:44:45"));
 trackElement.appendChild(StopTime);

 Element TaskId = doc.createElement("TaskId");
 TaskId.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("3"));
 trackElement.appendChild(TaskId);

 Element TotalTime = doc.createElement("TotalTime");
 TotalTime.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("1"));
 trackElement.appendChild(TotalTime);

 Element TrackDesc = doc.createElement("TrackDesc");
 TrackDesc.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("dello testing"));
 trackElement.appendChild(TrackDesc);

 Element TrackId = doc.createElement("TrackId");
 TrackId.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("0"));
 trackElement.appendChild(TrackId);

 TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 Transformer trans = null;
try {
    trans = transfac.newTransformer();
} catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
 trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

 //create string from xml tree
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
 DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
 try {
    trans.transform(source, result);
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 String xmlString = sw.toString();

//posting xml file to server

 DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.19:3334/cogglrestservice.svc/InsertTrack");     
 // Make sure the server knows what kind of a response we will accept
 httppost.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
 // Also be sure to tell the server what kind of content we are sending
 httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

 try
 {
 StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(xmlString, "UTF-8");
 entity.setContentType("application/xml");
 httppost.setEntity(entity);

 // execute is a blocking call, it's best to call this code in a thread separate from the ui's
 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

 BasicResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String strResponse = null;
    if (response != null) {
        try {
            strResponse = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.e("WCFTEST", "WCFTEST ********** Response" + strResponse);    


 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 ex.printStackTrace();
 }
 Toast.makeText(EditTask.this, "Xml posted succesfully.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: How to iclude this xml in StringEntity  
XML &xml=
    <HotelListRequest>
    <city>Seattle</city>
    <stateProvinceCode>WA</stateProvinceCode>
    <countryCode>US</countryCode>
    <arrivalDate>08/01/2012</arrivalDate>
    <departureDate>08/03/2012</departureDate>
    <RoomGroup>
    <Room>
    <numberOfAdults>2</numberOfAdults>
     </Room>
     </RoomGroup>
     <numberOfResults>1</numberOfResults>
         <supplierCacheTolerance>MED_ENHANCED</supplierCacheTolerance>
         </HotelListRequest>

Comment: I have just found this solution and it seems to be working for me. However, the strResponse variable is always null on a successful connection? I also need to be able to see the actual response the server fires back (my APi fires back a block of XML). How can I see this?

Comment: @PradeepSodhi How do  I sent it as get parameter and check the XML response

Comment: Thanks a ton for the rescue..:)

Answer (score 1):

```java
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("Your target Url");
 httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

 StringEntity entity = new StringEntity("<input>test</input>", "UTF-8");
 entity.setContentType("application/xml");
 httpPost.setEntity(entity);

 HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("targetDomain", 80, "http");
 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(targetHost, httpPost);
```

Comment: targethost with targetDomain, what is it for, where is declaration of httpClient?

Answer (score 0):

```java
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://foo/service1.asmx/GetUID");     


                     //XML example to send via Web Service.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("<myXML><Parametro><name>IdApp</name><value>1234567890</value></Parameter>");
            sb.append("<Parameter><name>UID1</name><value>abc12421</value></Parameter>");
                    sb.append("</myXML>");

            httppost.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
            httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1); 
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myxml", sb.toString());//WS Parameter and    Value           
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```