# android httppost method to post the xml content to the server

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest

I want to parse the xml content to the server so how can i do it....

```
<order>
    <orderItems>
    <itemId>9523</itemId>
    <lhmItemId>162327</lhmItemId>
    <itemQuantity>1122</itemQuantity>
    <instruction/>
</orderItems>

<contactInfo>

    <customerName>aaaaaaaaa</customerName>
    <email>xyz@abc.com</email>
    <mobile>1111111111</mobile>
    <phone>1111111111</phone>
    </contactInfo>
</order>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695796/how-to-send-an-xml-file-using-http-post-in-android-where-i-put-the-xml-files-in). you will get the idea to convert the string values into xml and than you will be able to post the values back to server. Here in the tutorial example its done by HttpPost but if u want to use HttpGet than just make it an HttpGet request.