# Sending a xml file to a web service in android

Tags: android, xml, file, http-post

Hello Friends I am trying to send an xml file stored in my sd card through my android app with the piece of code below:

```
    public class CartDetailsActivity extends Activity {
    File newxmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+GlobalVariables.ada_login+".xml");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cart_details);

        Button payButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.pay);
        payButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new PostXmlClass().execute();
            }





    });
}

    public class PostXmlClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
        CartDetailsActivity.this);

protected void onPreExecute() {
    this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
    this.dialog.show();
}
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String url = "http://mywebsite.com/myfolder/mypage.php";

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                    new FileInputStream(newxmlfile), -1);
            reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
            reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            //Do something with response...

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // show error
        } // inside the method paste your file uploading code
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // Here if you wish to do future process for ex. move to another activity do here

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
}
```

xml file is of the type:

```
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes' ?>
<root>
  <item>
    <code>ACT358</code>
    <price>110.00</price>
    <quantity>3</quantity>
    <totalcost>330.0</totalcost>
  </item>

<item>
  <code>ACT443</code>
  <price>110.00</price>
  <quantity>2</quantity>
  <totalcost>220.0</totalcost>
</item>
</root>
```

I don't know whats wrong with this code as it is not working and file does not get uploaded. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Post the code on the server side to receive the file.

Answer (score 1):

you can add this as `NameValuePair`

```
String xmlContent=getStringFromFile();//your method here
    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xmlData",
                        xmlContent));
```

and send as

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.ISO_8859_1));
```

OR If you want to send as a file you need to use the multi-part
[Ref Here:](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106)

Comment: where to add "List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("xmlData",
                    "xmlCOntent"));" in my particular code?

Comment: you can add any where before HttpPost method.

Comment: Your link is not helping my problem here. any other suggestions and examples codes are welcome. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
DataInputStream inputStream = null;

String pathToOurFile = "/data/file_to_send.mp3";
String urlServer = "http://192.168.1.1/handle_upload.php";
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";

int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

try
{
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

URL url = new URL(urlServer);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Allow Inputs & Outputs
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);

// Enable POST method
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

// Read file
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

while (bytesRead > 0)
{
outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}

outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

// Responses from the server (code and message)
serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

fileInputStream.close();
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//Exception handling
}
```

For more details, refer: http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/

These are the additional links if the above didn't work:

--> http://www.tecnojin.it/wordpress/?p=194

--> http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/

--> http://www.anddev.org/upload_files_to_web_server-t443-s15.html

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will work

```
// the file to be posted
String textFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sample.txt";
 Log.v(TAG, "textFile: " + textFile);

 // the URL where the file will be posted
 String postReceiverUrl = "http://yourdomain.com/post_data_receiver.php";
Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + postReceiverUrl);

 // new HttpClient
 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// post header
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

File file = new File(textFile);
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);
httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

// execute HTTP post request
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

if (resEntity != null) {

String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
Log.v(TAG, "Response: " +  responseStr);

// you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response
}

and php code.
<?php
// if text data was posted
if($_POST){
print_r($_POST);
}

 // if a file was posted
 else if($_FILES){
 $file = $_FILES['file'];
 $fileContents = file_get_contents($file["tmp_name"]);
 print_r($fileContents);
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code, it works fine for me:

//Creating xml file

DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
             dbfac.setNamespaceAware(true);
             DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
             try {
                docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             DOMImplementation domImpl = docBuilder.getDOMImplementation();
             Document document = domImpl.createDocument("http://coggl.com/InsertTrack","TrackEntry", null);
             document.setXmlVersion("1.0");
             document.setXmlStandalone(true);

             Element trackElement = document.getDocumentElement();

             Element CompanyId = document.createElement("CompanyId");
             CompanyId.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1"));
             trackElement.appendChild(CompanyId);

             Element CreatedBy = document.createElement("CreatedBy");
             CreatedBy.appendChild(document.createTextNode("6"));
             trackElement.appendChild(CreatedBy);

             Element DepartmentId = document.createElement("DepartmentId");
             DepartmentId.appendChild(document.createTextNode("4"));
             trackElement.appendChild(DepartmentId);

             Element IsBillable = document.createElement("IsBillable");
             IsBillable.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1"));
             trackElement.appendChild(IsBillable);

             Element ProjectId = document.createElement("ProjectId");
             ProjectId.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1"));
             trackElement.appendChild(ProjectId);

             Element StartTime = document.createElement("StartTime");
             StartTime.appendChild(document.createTextNode("2012-03-14 10:44:45"));
             trackElement.appendChild(StartTime);

             Element StopTime = document.createElement("StopTime");
             StopTime.appendChild(document.createTextNode("2012-03-14 11:44:45"));
             trackElement.appendChild(StopTime);

             Element TaskId = document.createElement("TaskId");
             TaskId.appendChild(document.createTextNode("3"));
             trackElement.appendChild(TaskId);

             Element TotalTime = document.createElement("TotalTime");
             TotalTime.appendChild(document.createTextNode("1"));
             trackElement.appendChild(TotalTime);

             Element TrackDesc = document.createElement("TrackDesc");
             TrackDesc.appendChild(document.createTextNode("testing"));
             trackElement.appendChild(TrackDesc);

             Element TrackId = document.createElement("TrackId");
             TrackId.appendChild(document.createTextNode("0"));
             trackElement.appendChild(TrackId);

             TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
             Transformer trans = null;
            try {
                trans = transfac.newTransformer();
            } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
             trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

             //create string from xml tree
             StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
             StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
             DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
             try {
                trans.transform(source, result);
            } catch (TransformerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             String xmlString = sw.toString();

//posting xml file to server

             DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.19:3334/cogglrestservice.svc/InsertTrack");     
             // Make sure the server knows what kind of a response we will accept
             httppost.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
             // Also be sure to tell the server what kind of content we are sending
             httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

             try
             {
             StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(xmlString, "UTF-8");
             entity.setContentType("application/xml");
             httppost.setEntity(entity);

             // execute is a blocking call, it's best to call this code in a thread separate from the ui's
             HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

             BasicResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String strResponse = null;
                if (response != null) {
                    try {
                        strResponse = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
                    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();  
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Log.e("WCFTEST", "WCFTEST ********** Response" + strResponse);    


             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
             ex.printStackTrace();
             }
             Toast.makeText(EditTask.this, "Xml posted succesfully.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

From [Sent Xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695796/how-to-send-an-xml-file-using-http-post-in-android-where-i-put-the-xml-files-in)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, hope this gonna help you.

**PHP web-service**

```
<?php
// Where the file is going to be placed
$target_path = "uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
}
?>
```

**Java Code**

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+GlobalVariables.ada_login+".xml"";
new uploadFiletoServer().execute(path);
```

and here is your uploadFile

```
class uploadFiletoServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Uploading file to server. Please wait ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            DataInputStream inStream = null;
            String existingFileName = path;

            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
            String urlString = url;
            try {
                // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                        existingFileName));
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                // Allow Outputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                // Don't use a cached copy.
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                // Use a post method.
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                        + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                // close streams
                Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
            }
            // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
            try {
                inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                String str;

                while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
                }
                inStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ioex) {
                Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to create folder name called `uploads` in the same directory where you have your web-service.

Answer (score 0):

I Tweaked your doInBackground to how i do the exact same thing: Give it a try:

```
     @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String url = "http://mywebsite.com/myfolder/mypage.php";

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(newxmlfile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
            String xml = sb.toString();


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(xml);
            se.setContentType("text/xml");
            httppost.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            //Do something with response...

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // show error
        } // inside the method paste your file uploading code
        return null;
    }
```

I wrote a dictionary tutorial while back where i send xml to web service, Have a look at it here for more info [Andorid Dictionary Tutorial](http://androidtutorials-codes.blogspot.com/2013/09/android-app-development-201-5th.html)