# How to Send Xml Data In HttpPost in Android

Tags: android, xml

I know that this is a duplicate Question. But i didn't get the proper answer. My question is that. I have some data and i want to convert that data into xml and i want to send this xml with HttpPost request. When This Post request is executed then it give me data in xml format. then i want to parse the xml data. Please tell me the best way to do it. I have read Some tutorial but I haven't get proper answer. is there no other way to convert object value into xml accounting to the class field Like marshaling and unmarshaling in java  please tell me the answer. Thanks in advance.  I have read some example here are some links. [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695796/how-to-send-an-xml-file-using-http-post-in-android-where-i-put-the-xml-files-in) and [here](http://androidcodeforbeginners.blogspot.in/2013/05/send-xml-data-from-android-to-php-server.html)